# Multiplying Taxes and Adding to Total Amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We don't always have to add taxes to order so I need a way that taxes will be bypassed by default unless specified.

So I have the following text box:

```
  <input  class="txt1" type="text" name="subtotal" value="" id="subtotal"
  size="16" tabindex="42" onChange="enableBeforeUnload();" 
  onKeyUp="enableBeforeUnload();">
```

I have this text box working correctly-it sums the values.

I have two text boxes that I'm trying to multiply by the tax percent and display the total:

```
 <input  class="txt1" type="text" name="tax" id="tax" value="1" size="16" tabindex="42"
  onChange="enableBeforeUnload();" onKeyUp="enableBeforeUnload();">

 <input  class="txt2" type="text" name="total1" value="" id="total1" size="16" 
 tabindex="42" onChange="enableBeforeUnload();" onKeyUp="enableBeforeUnload();">
```

I tried using the following with no luck:

```
 var tax = +$("#tax").val(),          // get tax and convert to a number
total = tax ? sum * tax : sum;   // if tax is a non-zero number multiply
                                 // otherwise just take the sum as is
```

and this:

```
 totAmt.val(sum + sum*parseFloat(taxAmt.val()/100));
```

I could not implement either correctly.
Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/thetylercox/jh2Ne/7/ i coul dnot get this to work correctly 
http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/demo.php its working fine here

Comment: The JS Fiddle you've link to has neither of your tax calculation methods in & doesn't seem to be doing anything at the moment… — is that right?

Comment: im new the js fiddle i have it working on my site i was just trying it out http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/demo.php @anotherdave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you are calling:

```
$("#tax")
```

But you don't have an element with an id of tax.  you could use:

```
$("input[name=tax]")
```

-edit->
So is the problem getting the values, or the logic in calculating the total?
You could throw your tax logic in a function:

```
function getTax(tax){
var taxFloat = parseFloat(tax)
if(isNaN(taxFloat)){
    return 1;
}else{
    return taxFloat;
}
}
```

Then use:

```
total = getTax($('#tax').val()) * sum;
```

Comment: Better to put the id on the `<input>` than trying to select by name. 1) The `<input>` should have an associated `<label>` and 2) it's possible (if unlikely with this example) that you may want to have two fields with the same name, but you wouldn't want to target both. Simpler to base all manipulations from ID from the get-go.

Comment: when i tried to impliment it i added the id tax to the element  i must have pasted the text box from prior i will edit the above axampe

Answer (score 0):

And what's that plus doing in your formula?
Should just be:

```
var tax = $("#tax").val()
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    calculateSum();
       $(".txt").keyup(calculateSum);
});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0,
        val;
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        if(val = +this.value)
            sum += val;
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    var tax = +$("#tax").val();
    $("#total1").html((tax ? sum * tax : sum).toFixed(2));
}

Answer (score 0):

try adding a function to do your calculations

total = getTax($('#tax').val()) * sum;